# Use java.time in Hibernate 5.1

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x, localdate

I'm using Hibernate 5.1 in my application. Now I want to convert all the java.util.date classes to the java.time java 8 classes. I changed all my source code to the new Java 8 standard. But when I query the first query that contains a mapping to a LocalData it throws an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate
```

The Hibernate-java8 jar is in my classpath.

Can someone help me to use java.time classes instead of the old java.util.date?
Do I need to configure something in my Hibernate config for it?

Comment: Can we see some code, please? The entity mapping and the query would be a good start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not about the support of `LocaleDate` by `Hibernate 5.1` the exception says that there's a `cast Exception` from `java.sql.Date` to `java.time.LocaleDate`.

If you check the [**`Hibernate 5.1` User Guide**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) you can see that Hibernate provides a replamcement type for the `java.time.LocaleDate` which is [`LocalDateType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-provided) class.

So instead of using `java.time.LocaleDate` you shoud use `org.hibernate.type.LocalDateType`  in your entities.